# unable to process files of a directory in for loop in linux

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, directory, file-rename

i have directory that has 2 sub-directories and that again has few sub-directory and they have some files. I need to rename all the files to append an html extension to the filenames.
the directory structure looks like this

```
main-directory
   sub-directory
   sub-directory
       sub-directory
          file1
          file2
          and so on to lot of files
```

now i could not use something like this

```
for file in main-directory/*
do
if [ -f "$file" ]
then `mv "$file" "$file.html"`
fi
done
```

because the for loop wont use the path recursively. so i used something like this

```
for file in `ls -1R main-directory`  // -1 for showing file and directory names separated by new lines and -R for recursive travel
do
if [ -f "$file" ]
then `mv "$file" "$file.html"`
fi
done
```

the above code is not able to rename files. to check whether the line

```
for file in `ls -1R main-directory`
```

is working i wrote something like this

```
for file in `ls -1R main-directory`
do
if [ -f "$file" ]
echo $file
done
```

this doesn't show anything. what can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use find and look into of type file and then -exec to change all the file and then appending the .html.

```
find main-directory -type f -exec mv -v '{}' '{}'.html \;
```

Comment: @Jasonw: whats wrong with the above for loop? and can you explain your command? what does {} do and why \ in the end?

Comment: @lovesh, first, you if loop hash syntax error. second, ls only list the content of the directory, and then the if check validate if the file is exists. For your implementation, the file will not be shown before the file is not exists. before the if check, try do a echo $file and then do a pwd, you will understand.

Comment: @Jasonw: i put an `echo $file` after `do` in for loop and i got a list of names and directories of main-directory each on a new line

Comment: @lovesh, this is my version, if you notice the $cur_dir and $file, the $cur_dir will always output where you execute this script. then the $file is the filename and not the absolute path. So when you do a check if [ -f "$file" ] ; bash could not locate the file. 



#!/bin/sh

for file in `ls -R main-directory`; do
  cur_dir=`pwd`
  echo "where $cur_dir file $file"
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo $file
  fi  
done

Comment: @Jasonw:: ya i got this i need to append the current directory name in front of the file

Comment: @lovesh, ok if you understand it or you can probably use the 1liner in the answer which is easier though.

Answer (score 1):

In your first `for` loop, the `mv` command should not be in back-ticks.

In your second `for` loop, the if-statement has incorrect syntax. There is no `then` or `fi`. It should be:

```
for file in `ls -1R main-directory`
do
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
   echo $file
fi
done
```

But even then, this won't work because `ls -1R main-directory` gives you just the file names, not the absolute paths to the file. Move your echo outside the if-statement to test:

```
for file in `ls -1R main-directory`
do
   echo $file
done
```

Therefor `ls -1R main-directory` is not a good way to get all files in the current directory. Use `find . -type f` instead.

Comment: why not backticks for `mv` in first `for` loop. ya i forgot to put `then`, `fi` and `done` in this post but i had this in my code

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I can never remember the `find ... -exec` syntax off the top of my head with the `{}` and the `\;`. Instead, I've fallen into the habit of just using a loop fed from find:

```
find main-directory -type f | while read file
do
    mv "$file" "$file.html"
done
```

`find` outputs each file to stdout and the `read file` will consume one line at a time and set the contents of that line to the `$file` environment variable. You can then use that anywhere in the body of your loop.

I use this approach to solve lots of little problems like this where I need to loop over a bunch of output and do something useful. Because it is more versatile, I use it more than the esoteric `find ... -exec {} \;` approach.

Another trick is to prepend you command with `echo` to do a quick sanity check before doing potentially damaging things to your system:

```
find find main-directory -type f | while read file
do
    echo mv "$file" "$file.html"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer to my question. people responded by 1 liners which are a neat approach but i didnt get much out of those 1 liners so here is something that i wanted

```
IFS=$'\n'   // this is for setting field separator to new line because the default is whitespace
dir=main-directory
for file in `ls -1R main-directory | sed 's/:$//'`  // -1 for showing file and directory names separated by new lines and -R for recursive travel
do
if [ -f "$dir/$file" ]
then `mv "$dir/$file" "$dir/$file.html"`
elif [ -d "$file" ]
then dir=$file
fi
done
```

here the `sed 's/:$//'` detects a `:` at the end of line and removes it. this was one of the things that prevented my code to run because whenever `ls -1R main-directory` detected a directory it appended a `:` at the end

Comment: The answers were one line because there isn't a reason to make it more than one line. I'd spend some time understanding the answers provided that use the `find` command instead of `ls`. Using `find`, you can avoid your issues above where you have to strip the `:` from the directory names and also keep track of the `dir` variable. Also, one issue that you didn't catch is dealing with spaces in the filenames or directories.

Comment: @Steve Prentice: i have already acknowledged that the the other answers are better but i wanted to see if there was a way i could do it with a for loop and yes i realized that i was not dealing for `spaces` in file names so i have changed the `field separator` to a newline